# Who distinguishes roll from role?

Tags: phonetics

I pronounce roll with the same vowel as the word all.

roll - [ɹɔɫ]

all - [ɔɫ]

But for role, I will often actually use the vowel in bowl

role - [ɹɔuɫ]

bowl - [bɔuɫ]

However, when I encountered someone typing roll instead of role, I realized they are homophones for that speaker. A lot of dictionaries list them as such.

Is this an uncommon spoken distinction? I could name a lot more words that are not homophones to me, like poll/pole

Comment: Where are you? What dialect do you speak?

Comment: In no way does *roll* ever rhyme with *fall*, if that's what you’re saying. The *r*-word in *barrel roll* sounds the same as in *starring role* (in my American English).

Comment: American English, roll, fall, stall all rhyme to me. But raw and Amon Ra do not. I have two back vowels, [ɔ] and [ɑ]; but I also have the diphthong [ɔu]

Comment: @iopq Where, specifically, in America? Do other people in your area/family also pronounce *roll* this way?

Comment: From California, but my family is from Ukraine so they don't speak English natively. I did notice a lot of people in my area merge ɔ with ɑ which I don't in the same places. I say father and bother the same, but I don't merge them before W or L.

Comment: You mention "I could name a lot more words that are not homophones to me" -- can you list some more of them?

Comment: (*Role* and *roll* are indeed homophones even for AmE speakers without the cot-caught merger, the father-bother merger, or any of the pre-/l/ mergers, so this is likely something idiosyncratic.)

Comment: Law/lo (and behold)/la (dee da) all three have different vowels, ɔ/ɔu/ɑ making a three way distinction

Comment: Slavic languages may shorten vowels as such. AE has long, wrong, and strong rhyming. But if I am teasing a Slavic speaker with "strong like bull" (and no article), the *strong* rhymes with strrrung.

Comment: Just to confirm, you pronounce _role_ with the LOT vowel, to rhyme with _doll_ and _knoll_ (as in grassy) and _moll_ (as in gangster) and _lol_ (as in cat)?  That may help to narrow down the characterization of your accent.

Comment: Wonder if the OP pronounces "rôle" influenced by French, although it doesn't seem a direct copy.

Comment: Just to throw in one from the other side of the pond; roll/role & poll/pole are homonyms or direct rhymes. Though there are some here who would hint at adding the 'w' sound into the simple long 'o' as a diphthong, they would do it equally for all four words. Roll & all do not rhyme. They do not share a vowel.

Comment: I don't pronounce role with the LOT vowel because I merge that with father. It's confusing to use that category for me. But yes, the general category is back vowels before L, W, U. So that would include knoll, but for some reason not doll which I would use the father vowel in.

Comment: @Tevildo — In no way does *knoll* rhyme with *doll*, *moll*, or *lol*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat - they do for me - southern English RP.

Comment: They do for me too, Yorkshire, N. BrE - 'noll' not 'nowl'.

Comment: To be clear: there is a well-known *doll/dole merger* in BrE, but that isn't relevant here, since *roll* (despite orthography) is in the *dole* class.

Comment: Also: does *bowl* have the same diphthong as *goat,* or is there a difference between the two? How narrow are the transcriptions in your questions intended to be? (As I recall, California English in particular can have a great deal of "GOAT-fronting," which can get cancelled by a following /l/.)

Comment: I guess goat can be close to [ɡ̥ɤʊtˀ] in that bowl [b̥oʊɫ] is more rounded, but it's probably not distinctive because [ɡ̥oʊtˀ] sounds equally correct. [ɡ̥əʊt] would sound British to me

Comment: Interesting about roll being in the dole class, maybe I'm pronouncing the word as a spelling pronunciation

Comment: Does comparing with the regional clips and IPA for [*cold*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/cold), [*holy*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/holy), not to mention [*full*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/full), [*wool*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/wool), [*toe*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/toe), [*all*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/all), [*long*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/long) suggest some values here?

Comment: A lot of the [ɑ] are clearly rounded, making them [ɒ]

Comment: For example, Chicago's all was not
 [ɑːɫ], but [ɒɫ]